# Modifying UILabel text property

Tags: swift, uilabel

I am trying to modify the text string shown in a UILabel. This is how I build it via code:

```
func buildLabel() -> UILabel {
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 40)
let myview = UILabel(frame: rect)
    myview.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
    myview.numberOfLines = 0
    myview.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    myview.sizeToFit()

    return myview
}
```

Then inside an other method I'm trying to simply recall this:

```
buildLabel().text = "whatever I put inside here"
```

but the string will never show up. Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm calling the addsubview after trying to set its text property, but still.

Comment: according to documentation, numberOfLines = 0 should mean that the string will wrap as many times as it's needed. Anyway, i've tried setting it to 5 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this.

```
self.view.addSubview(buildLabel("whatever I put inside here"))

func buildLabel(text : String) -> UILabel {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 40)
    let myview = UILabel(frame: rect)
    myview.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
    myview.numberOfLines = 0
    myview.text = text;
    myview.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    myview.sizeToFit()

    return myview
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was simply adding the whole subview like this:

self.view.addSubview(buildLabel())

When I type in the line you wrote, it doesn't let me go any further because the addsubview method is requiring a UIView to be passed, not a string!